# how can I free pedestrians from a waiting area according to train arrival schedule in Anylogic?

Tags: schedule, anylogic

I have train station model, and have train arrival schedule. I want pedestrians to wait in the waiting area until the train arrives and the passengers on the train get off the train first. I tried to use 'hold', event, and free() function call and release pedestrians from the waiting area by using a counter of pedestrians getting off the train and get on the escalator

*if the number of passengers getting off the train is equal to the passengers getting on the escalator then the counter will be equal to zero and this satisfy the condition where pedestrians in the waiting area should be released to get on the train.

if ( counter == 0 ) {

hold . unblock();

}

else {

hold. block();

}

however, it did not work. It either hold the pedestrians for ever or ignore the script and head to train even if the train has not arrived yet.

can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you are use a ped wait block in order to build your logic... if you want to control the waiting time, you need to use in the properties delay ends on free() function call... in which case the hold is not needed.

Then you can do the following instead:

```
if ( counter == 0 ) {

pedWait.freeAll();

}
```

Comment: Thank you Felipe. I tried what you suggested but it did not work. However, I managed to do it by adding a function block and put the code in the function block, and initiate the function using the event.

Comment: this IS a function if you were putting it somewhere else, then that's obviously a mistake

Comment: That's great. Thank you very much.